# Capturing form field value to pass into AJAX using BUTTON (not submit)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple form with one input.  The page is located here:
[Actual Page](http://partsconsign.com/?custid=1)

I want to be able to take the input from the field, capture it, run ajax to get the data, trigger a div to show below, and display the data without any page refresh or reset.  If I define the var value, this code works:

```
var query = '12';
$("#buttonToClick").click(function () {
    $("#divToShow").show();
    $.post('ajax/part_detail_by_partno.php', { part: query }, function(data) {
                $("#divToShow").html(data);
    });
});
```

I am using an auto-complete feature on the field, but even disabled, the following does not work:

```
var query = $("#fieldWithData").val();
    $("#buttonToClick").click(function () {
        $("#divToShow").show();
        $.post('ajax/part_detail_by_partno.php', { part: query }, function(data) {
                    $("#divToShow").html(data);
        });
    });
```

I'm assuming it's because I cannot cannot capture the data without actually submitting the form.  So I changed the "button" to a "submit" with no form action (no page reload).  But then #divToShow does not open as a result of a page-reload.  Take a look at the "Quick Find" box on my page.  How can I get the input from the user to trigger the div to display the data returned from ajax/part_detail_by_partno.php generated by the input from the user?  I've spent hours trying to figure this out.  I am new to jQuery and AJAX, and I appreciate your help!

Comment: Add return false to your click event and it doesn't submit anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're capturing the value of "query" outside the click action.  Move it inside the function.

Like this:

```
$("#buttonToClick").click(function () {
    var query = $("#fieldWithData").val();
    $("#divToShow").show();
    $.post('ajax/part_detail_by_partno.php', { part: query }, function(data) {
                $("#divToShow").html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt and CORRECT response!  I'll mark this one answered.